# Need correction in this code. I'm not able to run elif part in this program

Tags: python

I am not able access `elif` part :

```
total = input('What is the total amount for your online shopping?')
country = input('Shipping within the US or Canada?')

if country == "US":
    if total <= "50":
        print("Shipping Costs $6.00")
    elif total <= "100":
        print("Shipping Costs $9.00")
    elif total <= "150":
        print("Shipping Costs $12.00")

    else:
        print("FREE")

if country == "Canada":
    if total <= "50":
        print("Shipping Costs $8.00")
    elif total <= "100":
        print("Shipping Costs $12.00")
    elif total <= "150":
        print("Shipping Costs $15.00")
    else:
        print("FREE")
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can use int("50") to convert "50" from string to integer 50.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = input('What is the total amount for your online shopping?')
```

python input defaults to string data type. you have to convert to int to compare

```
total = int(input('What is the total amount for your online shopping?'))
```

Updating the working code :

```
total = int(input('What is the total amount for your online shopping?'))
country = input('Shipping within the US or Canada?')

if country == "US":
    if total <= 50:
        print("Shipping Costs $6.00")
    elif total <= 100:
        print("Shipping Costs $9.00")
    elif total <= 150:
        print("Shipping Costs $12.00")

    else:
        print("FREE")

if country == "Canada":
    if total <= 50:
        print("Shipping Costs $8.00")
    elif total <= 100:
        print("Shipping Costs $12.00")
    elif total <= 150:
        print("Shipping Costs $15.00")
    else:
        print("FREE")
```

Comment: if total <= "50":
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: here "50" is string . 
change to total <= 50 works .. 
50 without quotations.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings. Change your input to an integer with `total = int(input(...))` and compare it to numbers instead of strings: `if total <= 50:` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings when you want to compare integers, meaning you are comparing `ASCII` values instead.
See the following snippet:

```
total = "120"
if total <= "50":
    print("yes")
```

Which prints `yes` when you obviously won't expect it. Convert your strings to integers.